# Proxy Authorization in actionscript to avoid OS prompt

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, proxy-authentication

I have an air app and I want to add proxy-authorization header whenever my client is behind a proxy. I am adding 'proxy-Authoriztion' header in urlRequest headers but still I am getting the OS prompt for username/password.

```
var loader:HTMLLoader = new HTMLLoader();
var be:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();
be.insertNewLines = false;
be.encode("test" + ":" + "test");    
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://google.co.in");
urlRequest.authenticate = false;
urlRequest.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader("Proxy-Authorization","Basic "+ be.toString())); 
page.htmlLoader.load(urlRequest);
```

I checked fiddler and what I see is that
1st Response is 301 and proxy-authorization header is added
2nd Response is 407 and proxy-authorization header is not added.

After this I get the OS prompt.
Anybody has any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

I had that exact same problem, just for Authorization headers. Here is my solution:

```
var service:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
...
var encoder:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();
encoder.encode(userName+':'+password);
service.headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + encoder.toString();
...
service.send();
```

For some none apparent reason this works. Try that ( but remember to change the "Authorization" header in my example with "Proxy-Authorization")

Comment: I am using urlRequest, cannot try with HTTPService.

Comment: To send a single request with Basic Authentication the approach you have mentioned is good but in case where you need to make many requests e.g. loading a web page that is password protected this approach won't work. you need to use URLRequestDefaults.setLoginCredentialsForHost()